# How to use keyDown() and keyUp() in sikuli?

Tags: syntax-error, jython, sikuli

This is my code snippet,

```python
reg = selectRegion("Selected a region")
reg.keyDown(KEY_CTRL)
reg.keyUp()
```

My objective is to select some lines, as we do it by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and then scrolling down, but it throws

```python
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid key code
```

It's obvious that I have done something wrong, Could any one help me out with this??

Answer (score 2):

The documentation on [special keys](http://doc.sikuli.org/keys.html#special-keys) says to use `CTRL` with `keyDown()`.  `KEY_CTRL` is used with `type()` or other cases where you want to add the modifier key as a mask.  (And that's actually deprecated and should be `KeyModifier.CTRL` now, instead.)

For example:

```python
reg.keyDown(CTRL)
... some code that scrolls ...
reg.keyUp(CTRL)
```

Or to press the "down" key twice while holding <kbd>control</kbd>:

```python
reg.type(Key.DOWN + Key.DOWN, KeyModifier.CTRL);
```

(As a side-note, it's generally <kbd>shift</kbd> that's used as the modifier key for creating a selection and not <kbd>control</kbd>.)